# Rails / Shared strong parameters' definition between two controllers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, strong-parameters

having two items_controller, one for the api (in app/controllers/api/) and one for the backend (in app/controllers/backend)

The strong parameters are quite long (20 fields or something) and prompt to evolve a bit. That would not be impossible to maintain this list in both controllers, but as the needs are more or less the same on the create/updates actions, I'd be looking into sharing the strong parameters definition in a separate file that would be shared to both

I've tried to inherit those two with a super controller including only the strong parameter definition :

```
class SharedItemsController < ApplicationController
  private # not knowing all the prerequisites of this, I tried also using protected instead of private; same result 
    def item_params
       ....
    end
  end
end
class  Frontend::ItemsController < SharedItemsController
   ...
end
class  Api::ItemsController < SharedItemsController
   ...
end
```

No success, I'm stuck with unpermitted parameters

Hope to get some tips on this one here on SO;
best

Comment: What do you mean, no success? Should have worked.

Comment: Anyhow, using inheritance for sharing code is a bad idea. Try putting the strong params method in a module and include that.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev could google it, but i think i'd accept your answer if you had some pointers on this one, coming from an advised source. have to say i'm not that familiar with modules

Comment: Perhaps, this will help: http://www.railstips.org/blog/archives/2009/05/15/include-vs-extend-in-ruby/

Comment: @SergioTulentsev thanks I'll look into this. you make my day if i get aware of the reasons why using inheritance for sharing code is bad

Comment: In short, inheritance should be used for _specialization_. You have, say, Vehicle class. A Car is a special type of Vehicle. A Motorcycle is another special type of Vehicle. They _behave_ differently than Vehicle. That's when you use inheritance. In your case, there's no "is kind of" relationship.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev found plenty of reasons here http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/12439/code-smell-inheritance-abuse, thx for this enlightenment it starts to make sense

Answer (score 6, accepted):

thanks to @SergioTulentsev; in this case a basic and preferable pattern would be to use a module. For example in lib/items_controller_params.rb :

```
module ItemsControllerParams
  def item_params
    params.require(:item).permit(
       .. your fields here ...
    )
  end
end
```

Then it could be included in the concerned controllers like below :

```
  class Api::ItemsController < ApplicationController
    include ItemsControllerParams
    ...
  end
```

Answer (score -1):

I don't actually  get you why are you not putting

```
private

def item_params
    params.require(:item).permit(your_fields_name)
end
```

in particular controller ?

if you think you got 20-30 fields and it will be confusing for you to add all fields there and what if in future I need to use nested attributes then it will be even more complicated. So short hand

```
private

def item_params
    params.require(:item).permit!
end
```

permit with ! and that's it you no longer need to define every single column in params even if it's nested.
Good luck.

Comment: Did you miss the point? He needs this method in two controllers.

Comment: I could, but as this part of code is going to be the almost exact same, and is already quite long (I've shortened it but I already have nested attributes, so you can double up the count of fields), I felt like finding a way to correctly share it. Going into `permit!`-ing it all feels a bit yolo; but I could be wrong  thinking that for some reasons

Comment: "Going into permit!-ing it all feels a bit yolo; but I could be wrong thinking that for some reasons" buddy how will you learn if you think so much before you try something ;)

Comment: didn't wanted to mean anything wrong to you; even said i could be wrong. Still, I guess i'll learn more trying to understand how to use modules instead of skipping that part using permit!

Comment: From a security point of view this kinda defeats the strong parameters introduced by Rails 4.